# font-family shown in developer tool but doesn't apply inside froala editor

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api, froala

I'm facing a strange problem. I am using a font from google using `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Serif+Pro:400,600,700');` in `styles.scss` in an angular2 project. I'm using the font-family for a paragraph inside the froala editor. When I check the font family for the paragraph in dev tools, it shows that it is using the right font family. However, the font is clearly not the one I'm using because it looks completely different. I have tried to download the file and define a new `@font-face` but that doesn't work either. I'm not sure how to solve/debug this problem.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Serif+Pro:400,600,700');
...
p {
     font-family: 'Source Serif Pro', serif;
     font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I once had a similar problem, which was caused by a locally installed font. Have you tried on another machine?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I don't have another machine. I realized that the font-face shown in chrome dev tools doesn't mean anything. If you use a family which doesn't even exist, it will still show that font-family. I wonder how to debug this.

Comment: Hm, ok. It's hard to solve this problem for you without a running code example...

Comment: It is actually the editor issue.

Comment: @andreas thanks man, the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

So I solve the problem. I was using `iframe: true` inside the editor option which wraps all the editor content inside an iframe. This somehow messes with the style. Removing that solved the problem.